# Szekeres's sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic

## Definition

- \$a(1) = 1\$
- \$a(2) = 2\$
- \$a(n)\$ is smallest number \$k>a(n-1)\$ which avoids any 3-term arithmetic progression in \$a(1), a(2), ..., a(n-1), k\$.
- In other words, \$a(n)\$ is the smallest number \$k>a(n-1)\$ such that there does not exist \$x, y\$ where \$0<x<y<n\$ and \$a(y)-a(x) = k-a(y)\$.

## Worked out example

For \$n=5\$:

We have \$a(1), a(2), a(3), a(4) = 1, 2, 4, 5\$

If \$a(5)=6\$, then \$2, 4, 6\$ form an arithmetic progression.

If \$a(5)=7\$, then \$1, 4, 7\$ form an arithmetic progression.

If \$a(5)=8\$, then \$2, 5, 8\$ form an arithmetic progression.

If \$a(5)=9\$, then \$1, 5, 9\$ form an arithmetic progression.

If \$a(5)=10\$, no arithmetic progression can be found.

Therefore \$a(5)=10\$.

## Task

Given \$n\$, output \$a(n)\$.

## Specs

- \$n\$ will be a positive integer.
- You can use 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed, in which case \$n\$ can be \$0\$. Please state it in your answer if you are using 0-indexed.

## Scoring

Since we are trying to avoid 3-term arithmetic progression, and 3 is a small number, your code should be as small (i.e. short) as possible, in terms of byte-count.

## Testcases

The testcases are 1-indexed. You can use 0-indexed, but please specify it in your answer if you do so.

```
1     1
2     2
3     4
4     5
5     10
6     11
7     13
8     14
9     28
10    29
11    31
12    32
13    37
14    38
15    40
16    41
17    82
18    83
19    85
20    86
10000 1679657
```

## References

- [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonarithmeticProgressionSequence.html)
- OEIS [A003278](https://oeis.org/A003278)

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69271/8478) (If I understand your challenge correctly.)

Comment: @MartinEnder You did understand my challenge correctly.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Bḅ3‘
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QuG4hTPigJg&input=&args=OTk5OQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QuG4hTPigJgKxbzDh0c&input=&args=MCwgMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNiwgNywgOCwgOSwgMTAsIDExLCAxMiwgMTMsIDE0LCAxNSwgMTYsIDE3LCAxOCwgMTksIDk5OTk).

#### How it works

This uses 0-based indexing and the primary definition from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003278):

> Szekeres's sequence: **a(n)-1** in ternary = **n-1** in binary

```
Bḅ3‘  Main link. Argument: n

B     Convert n to binary.
 ḅ3   Convert from ternary to integer.
   ‘  Increment the result.
```

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, <s>37 36</s> 32 bytes

Using the given formula in the OEIS entry, using 0-based indices. Thanks @nimi for 4 bytes!

```
a 0=1;a m=3*a(div m 2)-2+mod m 2
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 28 bytes

```
lambda n:int(bin(n)[2:],3)+1
```

An anonymous function that takes input via argument and returns the result. This is zero-indexed.

**How it works**

```
lambda n    Anonymous function with input zero-indexed term index n
bin(n)      Convert n to a binary string..
...[2:]     ...remove `0b` from beginning...
int(...,3)  ...convert from base-3 to decimal...
...+1       ...increment...
:...        and return
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/0wspYa)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 113 bytes

```python
def f(n):
 i=1;a=[]
 for _ in range(n):
  while any(i+x in[y*2for y in a]for x in a):i+=1
  a+=[i]
 return a[n-1]
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/DlS2V9)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <del>28</del> 24 bytes

Using the same method as Dennis, with 0-based indexes:

```ruby
->n{n.to_s(2).to_i(3)+1}
```

Run the test cases on repl.it: https://repl.it/Cif8/1

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
b2b3h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=b2b3h&input=10)

0-based indexing

Same formula as jelly answer

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 5 bytes

```apl
1+3⊥⊤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/31Db@FHX0kddS/6nPWqb8Ki371FX86PeNY96txxab/yobeKjvqnBQc5AMsTDM/h/moIBV5qCIRAbAbExEJuA@CYA)

Jo King's suggestion.

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
1+3⊥2(⊥⍣¯1)⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///31Db@FHXUiMNIPGod/Gh9Yaaj7oW/U971DbhUW/fo67mR71rHvVuObTe@FHbxEd9U4ODnIFkiIdn8P80BQOuNAVDIDYCYmMgNgHxTQA)

Based on Dennis' Jelly answer.

Outputs are zero indexed.

```apl
1+3⊥2(⊥⍣¯1)⊢
           ⊢ Take argument
    2(⊥⍣¯1)  Encode in binary
  3⊥         Decode from ternary
1+           Add 1
```

Comment: With Dyalog Extended, this can be just [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/31Db@FHX0kddS/6nPWqb8Ki371FX86PeNY96txxab/yobeKjvqnBQc5AMsTDM/h/moIBV5qCIRAbAbExEJuA@CYA)! You can also save [2 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///31Db@FHXUqNHHTOA1KPexYfWG/5Pe9Q24VFv36Ou5ke9ax71bjm03vhR28RHfVODg5yBZIiHZ/D/NAUDrjQFQyA2AmJjIDYB8U0A) in Unicode

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>60</s> 42 bytes

0 Indexed

```
int s(int n){return n<1?1:3*s(n/2)-2+n%2;}
```

Using the implicit sequence definition from OEIS.
Thanks to Kevin for the improvement using only one return statement.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! :) You don't need the `static `, and you can also golf the `if(n==0)return 1;return 3*s(n/2)-2+n%2;` to `return n<1?1:3*s(n/2)-2+n%s;`. :) If you haven't seen it yet, [tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and [tips for golfing in all languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. Enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8, <s>52</s> 46 bytes

0 indexed.

```
i->Integer.valueOf(Integer.toString(i,2),3)+1;
```

Comment: You don't need the `return` but  you do need the semicolon afterwards

Comment: [This answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87189/how-many-rectangles-in-the-grid/87262#87262) that say semicolons aren't counted; I could change it either way, but is counting semicolons the consensus?

Comment: Eh, that's what they told me. I don't know if the consensus is as such.

Comment: Alrighty, no return plus semi-colon is shorter than before anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 11 bytes

```
1+(aTB2)FB3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fUFsjMcTJSNPNyfg/kGcCAA)

Based on Dennis' Jelly answer. Zero Indexed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

0-indexed

```
Ò¢n3
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0qJuMw&input=OA) or [run all test cases from the OEIS entry](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0qJuMw&input=NTgKLW0)

Same as most other solutions:

```
Ò¢n3     :Implicit input of integer U
Ò        :Negation the bitwise NOT of
 ¢       :U converted to a binary string
  n3     :Converted from a ternary string
```